# s3fs volume exposed via nginx

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, s3fs

I am mounting S3 bucket to Ubuntu VM with command

`root@factory:~# s3fs my-bucket /mnt/s3-bucket -o passwd_file=/etc/.passwd-s3fs -o noatime -o allow_other -o uid=1000 -o gid=1000 -o use_cache=/tmp -o default_acl=public-read-write`

This volume gets mounted correctly to VM. Also able to copy files from `/mnt/s3-bucket/*` to any other location.

```
root@factory:~# ls -alh /mnt/s3-bucket/
total 56K
drwxrwxrwx 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jan  1  1970 .
drwxr-xr-x 3 root   root   4.0K Jul 19 20:30 ..
-rw-r----- 1 ubuntu ubuntu  50K Jul 22 15:04 controller_1.34.0.tar
drwxr-x--- 1 ubuntu ubuntu    0 Jul 22 15:04 firmware
```

Don't know why these files are own by `ubuntu:ubuntu`

I am trying to serve this location through Nginx to download these files.

But when I click on the file name I get `403 Forbidden`

Tried to change file permissions

```
root@factory:~# chown -R root:root /mnt/s3-bucket
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/s3-bucket/controller_1.34.0.tar': Input/output error
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/s3-bucket/fixture_controller_2.1.3.tar': Input/output error
chown: changing ownership of '/mnt/s3-bucket': Input/output error
root@factory:~#
```

Tried to create file from VM 
    root@factory:~# touch /mnt/s3-bucket/test.txt
    touch: setting times of '/mnt/s3-bucket/test.txt': No such file or directory

nginx.conf :

```
server {
    listen         8080 default_server;
    server_name    localhost;
    keepalive_timeout 70;
    gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";
    gzip_vary on;
    gzip_proxied any;
    gzip_comp_level 6;
    gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    gzip_http_version 1.1;
    gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    location /s3 {
        alias /mnt/s3-bucket;
        autoindex on;
    }
}
```

Logs from `Nginx` :

```
2019/07/24 13:45:10 [error] 10777#10777: *2 open() "/mnt/s3-bucket/fixture_controller_2.1.3.tar" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 13.12.18.18, server: localhost, request: "GET /s3/fixture_controller_2.1.3.tar HTTP/1.1", host: "43.3.7.96:8080", referrer: "http://43.3.7.96:8080/s3/"
2019/07/24 13:45:18 [error] 10777#10777: *2 open() "/mnt/s3-bucket/controller_1.34.0.tar" failed (13: Permission denied), client: 13.12.18.18, server: localhost, request: "GET /s3/controller_1.34.0.tar HTTP/1.1", host: "43.3.7.96:8080", referrer: "http://43.3.7.96:8080/s3/"
```

What I am missing ? How can i server downloadable S3 files through Nginx

Comment: There are at least two other likely better ways to handle this.  The first would be to sign URLs and redirect to them, letting S3 serve the load directly.  This will save you some bandwidth costs.  If for some reason you don't want to do that, the next thing to try would be to proxy S3 directly.  I say this because I think you'll find that the S3 FUSE driver is a bit tricky by nature, and will fail you once in awhile.

Comment: Each individual URL gets signed on-the-fly.  You could serve whatever you wanted, but you'll need some script server-side.  (Surely someone has a Lua script for Nginx for this?)

Comment: Please post your `nginx` config that you used. And also the output of `ls -alh /mnt/s3-bucket`

Comment: Try doing `chown -R root:root /mnt/s3-bucket` from inside the container and see if it works afterwards

Comment: Also please let use know if you are running `s3fs` inside the container or on the host?

Comment: @roy, try to run the `s3fs` command from a root shell instead of the normal `ubuntu` user. Also if you can add the nginx logs when the error happens, it would be great

Comment: Updated with more details

Comment: `ps aux|grep nginx` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The files inside the S3 bucket are owned by `ubuntu:ubuntu` because the S3 bucket was mountet with the params `-o uid=1000 -o gid=1000`. These are the IDs for the user **ubuntu** and the group **ubuntu**.

The nginx worker process, which handles http requests, runs as an other user. Usually it's **www-data**.

If you want to enable nginx to access the files inside the S3 bucket you have to replace **uid** and **gid** with the corresponding values for **www-data**.

`id -u www-data` displays the **uid** and `id -g www-data` displays the **gid**